# How to set the date format to ISO 8601 or RFC 3339 in GrapheneOS?

Tags: custom-roms, localization, date-and-time

How can I set the date format to ISO 8601 (e.g. 2023-04-29) or RFC 3339 in GrapheneOS?

Comment: Do you have root? Magisk, twrp? I couldn't find anything relevant for graphene os particularly.

Comment: @44yu5h It is a fresh installed GrapheneOS so I guess that I am able to get root permissions somehow.

Comment: Uhh.. I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you flash magisk? Also i found this "I ran into same problem. It seems to be in many ROMs that you have to change the language to access other date-time formats. I had to change for instance to German, since none of the options for English supported DD.MM.YYYY format."